# ajax multiple data sent parameters php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

whats wrong with this?

EDIT:

```
 $check = $row['publish'] == 1 ? 'true' : 'false';
```

It works when I want to unpublished, but if the checkbox is empty I cannot publised.

```
 OnClick="doAction(<?php echo $check;?>, <?php echo $id;?>);"



function doAction(check,id){
 $.ajax({

      type: "GET",
      url: "test.php",
      data: "check=" + check + "&id=" + id,
      success: function(msg){
                 alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
               }
 });
}
```

and the file test.php:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
        $check = $_GET['check'];
        if ($check == "false"){
            $query = mysql_query("update article set publish = 1 where id =" . $id);
            echo "Published";
        }
        else {
            $query = mysql_query("update article set publish = 0 where id =" . $id);
            echo "Unpublished";
        }
```

I cannot display the id in the test.php file.it gives me nothing. But in the doAction parameters are(.., id) so it's been sent but I don t receive it in the ajax call and then in file. Why?

Comment: Assigning `$check` as *checked* or *unchecked*. And, In **test.php**, condition in `if` is `$check == "false"`. Why?

Comment: Try out this:  `$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "test.php?check="+ check + "&id = " + id,
      success: function(msg){
                 alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
               }
 });`

Comment: then how to assign the $check? in test.php if I write echo $check it gives me the( id, false) if I unpublished. but when i click the checkbox to published only it checks but doesn;t return anything, neither id or check status.

Comment: the problem is with the data you are passing to your function doAction(check, id). check that first!

Answer (score 1):

Try change:

```
data: "check=" + check + "&id = " + id,
```

To:

```
data: "check=" + check + "&id=" + id,
```

And you should define what will be response HTML , JSON etc. use for this example:

```
dataType: "JSON"
```

Comment: doesn't work. the problem I think is with $check = $row['publish'] == 1 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked';. It doesn't work for unchecked.

Comment: Edit your code to current revision. And try change $row['publish'] == 1 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'; to $row['publish'] == 1 ? 'true' : 'false'; because you try check that value not checked or unchecked. Pass to html

Comment: Show what u got in var_dump($_GET["id"]), var_dump($_GET["check"]); before if

Comment: now it works, it really works but it doesn;t remain in the checkbox the values. I mean if it's 1 in db it's not checked.

Comment: So change $row['publish'] == 1 ? 'true' : 'false';  to $row['publish'] == 1 ? 'false' : 'true'; I do not know what about you in the database represents the value 1 is you need to set an appropriate value to Your code to run what I gave must act

Comment: I resolve it. I stored in another variable "checked" or not. and that's it. I displayed it in the input, after the value. thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the value in arguments use below code.

```
 OnClick="doAction('<?php echo $check;?>', '<?php echo $id;?>');"
```